# Query For get Row Count with Condition

Tags: mysql

I have one table called tbl_vendors_report
Where column called vr_status in which I am saving status of vendor like
1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4
where 1 is for pending, 2 is for success, 3 is for blocked and 4 is for suspended

Now I am looking for get count of row like how many rows have 1, how many have 2, how many have 3 and how many have 4 so I can get idea how many is pending, how many is success and so on

I have tried query like below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_vendors_report GROUP BY vr_status
```

it's giving me counting like this

[image]

But it's not enough for me to think which one is count of 1 and which one is count of 2 and so on.

Comment: So select another column that does give you a clue, like `SELECT vr_status, COUNT(*) ....`

Answer (score 2):

Unless I have missed something, this is as simple as including `vr_status` in the output:

```
SELECT  vr_status,
        COUNT(*)
  FROM  tbl_vendors_report
  GROUP BY vr_status
```

This will show you, by status, what the count is.